# Require a gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'd like to include unitwise in my project, so I added it in the Gemfile and I want to use the core extensions of this gem in a model, so I have to require 'unitwise/ext' which isn't by default. Should I require this file in every models I use it, or is there a way to require it one time for the whole project?

Comment: Are you using Rails, Sinatra, or some other framework? Or just straight Ruby?

Answer (score 7):

You can require it once either by creating an `initializer` for it, or adding this line to `application.rb`.

```
require 'unitwise/ext'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create separate ruby file in `config/initializer/` to `require unitwise/ext` which will be available in all place in the project or you could require in `application.rb`, here also it will be available everywhere in application.

It is better add one line in `application.rb`, instead creating separate file in `initializer` to require that file.

Answer (score 0):

Now rails use `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` in an `config/application.rb`, so usually you do not need to require a gem explicitly.